# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest returns "remote name could not be resolved" but not proxy error

Tags: powershell, url, proxy, dns

I am trying to download a page using `wget` (alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`) in powershell. The page in question is `www.privatahyresvärdar.nu`.

When using Internet Explorer I can navigate to `www.privatahyresvärdar.nu` but I cannot run wget from powershell nor can i `ping` the site. Neither command can resolve the hostname.

I have followed several advice on SO and other sites commenting on using Proxies as an error source for `wget` failing, but i am not using any Proxy.

Please help me identify the error source!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a moment of clarity it struck me that it might be an encoding error! After replacing the hostname with [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) with an online punycode encoder ([first hit on google](https://www.punycoder.com/)) it worked like a charm!

[image]

Comment: I get this error whenever I have my azure vpn connected.

Comment: That sounds more like a proxy problem to me. Check out those quations and answers.